# NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS undefined in C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, process

Hello SOF C++ programmers :)

**Problem** : A supposedly built-in constant is not recognised at compile time, while it should. The constant is `NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS`, used in the function `CreateProcess` referenced here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**Context** : there is this software, that I didn't write, that I need to build and run. It is written in C++, programming language I do not know, and is build/run from Visual Studio 2008. And I didn't write the software. I have been demo-ed the software 4 weeks ago, for knowledge transfer : how to build it using Visual Studio 2008 on an XP PC for another device (embedded device), and how to use it once it is run. So everything worked fine at that time, that why I am assuming that the problem doesn't come from the source code (but maybe it does). Now, given the same codebase, I need to build it and run it on my own. And when I build it on VS2008, I get this error :

`error C2065: 'NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS' : undeclared identifier`

triggered by this function call :

`CreateProcess(this->ApplicationName,  szr,  NULL,  NULL,  FALSE,  NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,  NULL,  NULL,  &sui,  &processInfo)`

where `szr` is defined as such :

`TCHAR * szr = (TCHAR *)((*it).commandLine).c_str();`

I googled things around, and from what I understood, this constant `NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS` is built in. The doc at this link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reads : `By default, the priority class of a process is NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS`

So it's not a constant that the programmer defined for their own purpose. The libraries loaded in the class are :

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
```

and some other customs "header.h" files, written in the source code (Header files directory in VS2008).

Any ideas on what could be causing the problem, or what I should try out to reduce the list of possible issues ?

Comment: Since normal priority is the default anyway, just change that parameter to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you're building for an embedded system. [Windows Embedded does not support priority classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488350.aspx), so the priority-class constants are not defined in that compilation environment.

Comment: Ooooh OK. So I do not have the right codebase then. I must have used the codebase for running the app on a PC. Thank you so much @Rob Kennedy !!